# Epsilon-n proof confusion

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

So, I'm told I did something wrong on this epsilon-n proof but I really don't know what.

I'm told to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{5n+1}{n+3} = 5 $$

I begin by setting $\epsilon > 0$ and searching for $k$ such that for every $ n > k$, $$\left|\frac{5n+1}{n+3} - 5\right| < \epsilon$$
$$\left|\frac{5n+1}{n+3} - 5\right| = \left|\frac{5n+1 - (5n+15)}{n+3}\right| =  \left|\frac{-14}{n+3}\right| = \frac{14}{n+3} < \epsilon$$

(the last equality being valid since $n>0$ is definitely  true)

$$14 < n\epsilon + 3\epsilon$$
$$ n > \frac{14-3\epsilon}{\epsilon}$$
So set $k = \left \lceil{\frac{14-3\epsilon}{\epsilon}}\right \rceil$ and for every n > k, $$\left|\frac{5n+1}{n+3} - 5\right| < \epsilon$$  by what's shown above.

The issue I'm having is that I'm told (by my instructor, who deducted a point from this problem because of it) a better $k$ is in fact $\left \lceil{\frac{14}{\epsilon}}\right \rceil$, and I don't know why that would be or how I would get that $k$ to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that the lower bound is "wrong"; it is that the lower bound is unnecessarily complicated.

For all $n \geq 1$ we have
$$
\bigg| \frac{5n+1}{n+3} - 5 \bigg| = \bigg|\frac{5n+1 - 5n - 15}{n+3} \bigg| = \frac{14}{n+3} < \frac{14}{n};
$$
from this it is clear that
if $\varepsilon > 0$, then to make $14/n < \varepsilon$ it suffices to make $n > 14/\varepsilon$; hence for every $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $n \geq \lceil 14/\varepsilon \rceil + 1$ only if
$$
\bigg| \frac{5n+1}{n+3} - 5 \bigg| < \varepsilon.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the inequality
$$\frac{14}{n + 3} < \frac{14}{n} < \epsilon.$$
to determine $k$.

Comment: Does that mean that my k (or N, same thing) is wrong? Or is it just a simpler way to do the problem?

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer.

Comment: @StatGod I fail to see how this is a "better" $k$. It's merely a trick to make your work easier in finding a $k$ that fits the inequality. Correct me if I'm somehow wrong here, but the poster explicitly and algebraically solved for the minimum $k$ and therefore, in my eyes, an ideal one to use.

Comment: Of course, this is not ``better" but just simpler. The OP's answer is of course also acceptable. I just want to let him know how to get the $k$ that he was told.

Comment: Could you clarify why that's "allowed"? I mean, couldn't $\frac {14}{n}$ actually be $ > \epsilon$?

Comment: If you take $k$ to be $\lceil \frac{14}{\epsilon} \rceil$, then for all $n > k$, of course you can get $\frac{14}{n} < \frac{14}{k} < \frac{14}{14/\epsilon} = \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what has been said in the comments on StatGod's answer, I would say the instructor's value for $k$ **is** better than yours.  It's equally good for the proof and it makes the working simpler; how is that not better?

However I would also say that your instructor was being extremely harsh in deducting marks for this.

On the other hand, it's worth noting that in other cases, the "straightforward" approach you have given may not quite work.  For example, show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}=1\ .$$
We have
$$\left|\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}-1\right|=\frac1{n^2+1}\ ,$$
and making this less than $\epsilon$ in the "obvious" way gives
$$n>\sqrt{\frac1\epsilon-1}\ .$$
Problem is, the RHS is meaningless if $\epsilon>1$.  Now in a sense this is irrelevant since we are interested in small $\epsilon$, but on the other hand if we want to do things precisely we must recognise that the property is supposed to be true for **all** positive $\epsilon$.  So in this case it is definitely better to say that
$$\frac1{n^2+1}<\epsilon$$
is true if
$$\frac1{n^2}<\epsilon$$
which is true if
$$n>\frac1{\sqrt\epsilon}\ .$$