# Epsilon-n proof with polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

So I asked to evaluate the following limit using the definition of a limit:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{5n^2+7}{2n^2-n} $

So first by dividing by $n^2$ I get that  $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{5n^2+7}{2n^2-n} = \frac{5}{2}$

I understand that it must then follow that:

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \mid $ if $n>N $ then

$|\frac{5n^2+7}{2n^2-n} - \frac{5}{2}| < \epsilon$

$|\frac{5n^2+7}{2n^2-n} - \frac{5}{2}| = |\frac{5n^2 - 5n^2 + \frac{5}{2}n + 7}{2n^2-n}| = |\frac{\frac{5}{2}n+7}{2n^2-n}|$

But I am not sure how to simply this further? (although I have looked at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491710/epsilon-n-proof-confusion))

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @KennyLau "I am not sure how to simply this further "

Comment: Simplify this further in order to?

Comment: @KennyLau isolate $n$ in order to complete the proof

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is to find a bound for the polynomial. You can let $N > 7$, so that $7n^{-1} < 1$, and it follows
$$ \left| \frac{5n/2+7}{2n^2-n} \right| = \left| \frac{5/2 + 7n^{-1}}{2n -1} \right| \leq \left| \frac{7/2}{2n -1} \right|
$$
Moreover, since $2n - 1 > n$ for $n > N > 7$,
$$ \left| \frac{7/2}{2n -1} \right| \leq \left| \frac{7/2}{n} \right|
$$
Can you find the appropriate $N$ for the above to be less than $\epsilon$ now?

Comment: So we choose $n > \frac{7}{2\epsilon}$ and substitute this back into 
$\frac{5n^2+7}{2n^2-n}$? (and then follow this through to show that this is indeed less than $\epsilon$?

Comment: @Inazuma You need to choose $N = \max(7,7/2\epsilon)$ since $N$ must be greater than $7$ for this reasoning to work. You don't need to substitute $n$ back since these steps guarantees $|\frac{5n^2+7}{2n^2-n} - \frac{5}{2}| <|7/2n|$.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Thanks